colcon build cannot build the entire packages (navigation2)
I tried to build navigation2 with colon build.
(https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2)
Despite the fact that navigation2 has many packages,
when I try colcon build, it only builds one package - nav2_gazebo_spawner.
What is the problem?


Please post console output as code formatted text and not as a screen shot. See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Also please provide enough context to know what you've installed and what's in your workspace.

Try the following

rosdep install


rosdep install -r -y 
--from-paths ./src 
--ignore-src


colcon build


colcon build \   --symlink-install

